# an effective way to find duplicates inside a list with tuples, summing up the value of tuples and deleting used duplicate tuples

Tags: python-3.x, list, sum, tuples

I need to solve the problem with calculation of values of duplicates and then removing duplicates.

I need most efficient pattern to summarize values inside of tuples and then remove used duplicate.

```
(name, id, age, count)

facts = [('john', 1, 22, 1),('smit', 2, 17, 1),('john', 1, 22, 2),('nick', 3, 43, 1),('john', 1, 22, 1)]


from operator import itemgetter


def sum_and_sort_facts(self, facts:list):

    if len(facts) <= 1:
        return facts

    buffer_list = []
    for i, f in enumerate(facts):
        if buffer_list and f[1] in [x[1] for x in buffer_list]:
            continue
        for ic, fc in enumerate(facts):
            if i == ic:
                continue
            if f[1] == fc[1]:
                buffer_list.append((f[0], f[1], f[2], f[3] + fc[3]))
        buffer_list.append(f)

    return sorted(buffer_list, key=itemgetter(3), reverse=True)
```

I want to get:
facts = [('john', 1, 22, 4),('smit', 2, 17, 1),('nick', 3, 43, 1)]

Comment: please format your code correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one line with lists of comprehensions:

```
output = list(set([(x[0], x[1], x[2], sum([y[3] for y in facts if y[0]==x[0]])) for x in facts]))
```

> [('smit', 1, 17, 1), ('nick', 1, 43, 1), ('john', 1, 22, 4)]

It could also be done with Pandas, preserving 'original' order :

```
import pandas as pd
data = [('john', 1, 22, 1),('smit', 1, 17, 1),('john', 1, 22, 2),('nick', 1, 43, 1),('john', 1, 22, 1)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.groupby(by=[0,1,2]).agg({3: 'sum'}).reset_index()
output = [tuple(l) for l in df.values.tolist()]
print(output)
```

> [('john', 1, 22, 4), ('nick', 1, 43, 1), ('smit', 1, 17, 1)]

Comment: thank you @sebastien-d. very nice. I like first one -) it works. exactly what i want.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.